# Error reading in date using Zoo in R

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to use the Zoo package to read in daily observations, some of which are not consecutive. The first three lines are:

```
Date         Year   ID       DWT    Build CargoSize LoadArea DischargeArea Price Speed 
25-May-07    2007 8004351   294739  1982   262000       AG       ECI        79   14.5                
11-Feb-08    2008 8004363   294739  1983   261000       AG       ECI        84   14.5                
11-Feb-08    2008 8003459   294739  1984   265000       WAF      SPOR       89   14.5
```

I get the following error:

```
z <- read.zoo("multiplier_test.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE, format="%d-%b-%y")
Warning message:
In zoo(rval3, ix) :
some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not        unique
```

The goal is to regress Price on some of these variables, including Date, in which I would like to fit a polynomial to (using a partially linear model with the bs function). The error occurs I believe because there are multiple dates that are the same. This represents a separate transaction; I want to capture the variance between these observations so don't want to aggregate and lose degrees of freedom.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your `multiplier.csv` file? I imagine the error is something to do with your input. You should always give a Minimal Working Example in order for people to reproduce any errors you are getting.

Comment: You are correct, when I got rid of some columns the error went away (& don't need them anyway). I've edited the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occur because you try to convert a string with more than **1000** characters to date.